# How to navigate UITabBarController to ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `TabBarController` inside I am loading two `ViewControllers`.

```
import UIKit

class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
```

**Images:**

[image]

```
class AttendanceViewController: UIViewController,UIApplicationDelegate,
    UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UINavigationControllerDelegate,
    CLLocationManagerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if  Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
        //Below code is not working
        let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
        print("user is not login in redirect to login page")
        return
    }else{
        print("User Successfully loginedin")
    }
}

}
```

> **Note :** I have two view controller like **AttendanceViewController** and **TaskViewController** I want to check if user is not login then I want to redirect to my
>   **LoginViewController** I tried above code it's was not working

Comment: Are these both VC inside your tabBar?

Comment: @wings yes bro...`AttendanceViewController`  I am cheking if your is not login redirect to `loginViewController` but its not working..it's coming inside `if` loop but `LoginViewController` is not displaying..

Comment: make sure your `AttendanceViewController ` is wrapped into a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: @Torongo After adding `UINavigationController` now it working bro..but it's overlapping  means loginviewController showing ontop of the TabBarviewController

Comment: LoginViewController is inside the tabBar? I suggest that if the user is not logged in instead of pushing the LoginViewController set it as root view, doing that the view flow will start from the loginViewContoller.

Comment: @FedeHenze no sir....Inside TabBar I have **Attendance** and **Task** Viewcontroller....`LoginViewController` is separate

Comment: @GowthamanM is LoginViewController in another Storyboard?

Comment: Save the login state

Comment: @GowthamanM if LoginVC is not in the TabBarController setting it as a root view controller should work.

Comment: @RobertDresler I am new to iOS I am not getting what you are asking..still   I created one ViewController from storyboard then I linked my LoginViewControlller.

Comment: @GowthamanM see my edited answer

Comment: @RobertDresler ya sure give me sometime will check and let u know..Thanks bro

Comment: move your login checking code to `TabBarViewController`, and assign `LoginViewController ` to rootWindow (instead of pushing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I just created an example it will help you:-

I just use `userdefaults` to save loginState

Here is:-

**1). TaskViewController**

I just created a signOut button in it

```
import UIKit

class TaskViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var signOutButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    signOutButton.layer.cornerRadius = signOutButton.layer.frame.height/2
}



@IBAction func signOutButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")  // here I remove the boolean value
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
    let loginVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    let rootVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVc)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = rootVc

}



}
```

**2). AttendanceViewController** - I didn't created anything in it

```
import UIKit

class AttendanceViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


}
```

These both controllers are inside `TabBarController` which is `HomeController`

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

}
```

I created it in `Main.storyboard` file:-
[image]

And LoginViewController created in `login.storyboard` file 
[image]

**LoginViewController:-** here saved the loginState

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = loginButton.layer.frame.height/2
}


@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeController") as! HomeController
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = viewController

}

}
```

And last in `Appdelegate.swift` check the loginState in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like this:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let userLoginStatus = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
    print(userLoginStatus)

    if(userLoginStatus)
    {
        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let centerVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeController") as! HomeController
        window!.rootViewController = centerVC
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {

        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        let centerVC = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
        window!.rootViewController = centerVC
        window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

Here is the full project - https://www.dropbox.com/s/3d34raovyx6orda/saveLogin.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks bro it's helped me lot

Comment: happy coding :D

Comment: what do you want to achieve on that question?... I didn't understand

Comment: Are you practising this code if then share it on GitHub or dropbox :D

Comment: hi bro....can you pleas help me refer this link.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810969/how-to-append-special-character-in-ios-using-swift?noredirect=1#comment94471584_53810969 what is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

### **Present UIViewController**

Code you wrote would work if your ViewControllers were embed in `UINavigationController`, which they're not. So instead of pushing `UIViewController` from `UINavigationController` which doesn't exist you can just present your `LoginViewController`. So replace this:

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

with

```
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as? LoginViewController
present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

### **Embed in UINavigationController**

Alternatively you can embed your `UIViewController` in `UINavigationController` and set segue with identifier and then perform this segue to `LoginViewController`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**7. Perform segue**

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Comment: nside TabBar I have Attendance and TaskViewcontroller....LoginViewController is separate

Comment: it's working but my LoginVIewController is not showing the My UI Design sir

Comment: but this is not problem of this code. Maybe some mistake in LoginViewController?

Comment: @GowthamanM btw, you can try alternative way (edited answer).

Comment: Thank you sir..will check it

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check it in `appDelegate`. Nowadays I am also working with `UITabbarcontroller`.I suggest to set a tag(using userDefaults) for checking that the user is logging in or not . And my code is

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , UITabBarControllerDelegate , GIDSignInDelegate{

    var window: UIWindow?

    var userCurrentLocation : CLLocation?
    var mapView : GMSMapView?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "LoginStatus")as? String == "1"
        {
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initailVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar")
            let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initailVC)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navVC
        }

        return true
    }
```

I am using this code to check if the user is logging in it will redirect into `TabBarController` and if not it will remain in LoginVC.

Answer (score 0):

- Embed your `UITabBarController` in a `UINavigationController`

  `UINavigationController(rootViewController: UITabBarController(nibName: "TabBarNibName", bundle: Bundle.main))`
- Just push from the navigation controller of your TabBarController

  `tabbarcontroller.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)`

Comment: `UITabBarController -> Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller)` options are hidden bro...other ViewController it's showing....only UITabBarController I am not able to set the NavigationController