# How to append Special character in iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am new to iOS please consider.I want to post some data to server, but I am not able to send **Mobile number** `+91` and **bloodGroup** `A+`..it was sending to firebase `+` is replace with space `" "` like this  `( 91) and (A )`

```
 func addEmployees(){
    let photoUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pickcel-1241.appspot.com/o/task.careGallery%2FGroup%2018aasa.png?alt=media&token=4e0ac8f6-134a-4807-9fef-f44eabe9f6a8";

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let mobilenumber = Auth.auth().currentUser?.phoneNumber
    var employeeDetails = [String : AnyObject]()
    employeeDetails["OID"] =  getOID() as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["MID"] = userID as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["email"] = "ssinth@gmail.com" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["firstName"] =  "First Name" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["lastName"] =  "last name" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["isManager"] = "true" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["regMedia"] = "mobile" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["shortDestination"] =  "btm" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["address"] =  "+btm" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["createdDate"] = getdateformat() as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["orgName"] = "Test Org" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["photoUrl"] =  photoUrl as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["officeOpenTime"] =  "09:00" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["officeCloseTime"]  = "18:00" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["phoneNumber"] =  labelmobile.text as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["bloodGroup"] =  "A+" as AnyObject
    employeeDetails["empId"] = "abcd" as AnyObject

    let convertedvalue : String = convertToParameters(employeeDetails)

    print("convertedvalues :   \(convertedvalue)")


    let myUrl = URL(string: "https://us-central1-pickceltest.cloudfunctions.net/rebliss/createNewUser");

    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let postString = convertedvalue;

    print("start create employee")
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
          print("start create employee  =successfull")

        print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

        do {
             print("start create employee  =parsing problems   ")
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {
               // print("resultjson=one : ",self.json)
                print("resultjson=two   : ",parseJSON)       
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
 }
```

**function** convertToParameters

```
  func convertToParameters(_ params: [String: AnyObject?]) -> String {
        var paramList: [String] = []

        for (key, value) in params {
            guard let value = value else {
                continue
            }
           let scapedKey = key
           let scapedValue = value
            print("employee add status objects   =   ","\(scapedKey)=\(scapedValue as AnyObject)")
            paramList.append("\(scapedKey)=\(scapedValue as AnyObject)")
        }
        return paramList.joined(separator: "&")
    }
```

**Json Error:**

```
resultjson=two   :  {
    error =     {
        code = "auth/invalid-phone-number";
        message = "The phone number must be a non-empty E.164 standard compliant identifier string.";
    };
    success = 0;
}
```

**Error in firebase console:**

[image]

Comment: you need to percentage encode the `+` symbol explicitly, otherwise it is interpreted as a _space_ – you can read more about [how Apple handles the `+` character as default](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents/1407752-queryitems), _(spoiler: it does not do percentage encoding on that)_

Comment: @holex can you please suggest some reference link how to solve this issues
...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551816/swift-encode-url may help.

Answer (score 1):

Actual issue with you is your parameters not getting properly url encoded.

**Temporary Solution for your code:**

In your `convertToParams` method, make following changes:

```
let scapedKeyEncoded =  scapedKey.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed);
let scapedValueEncoded =  scapedValue.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed);
paramList.append("\(scapedKeyEncoded)=\(scapedValueEncoded)"
```

Note: Your scapedValue must be String, so, make employeeDetails as [String:String].

**Permanent Solution(Perfect way for encoding query parameters):**

For this, you can change your code to something like this:

1. Remove `convertToParameters` method
2. Add following method in place of it

   ```
   class func getURLRequestWith(urlStr:String, paramsDict:[String:String]?, isParamsAsQuery:Bool, isParamsAsBody:Bool) -> URLRequest? {

   guard var components = URLComponents(string: urlStr) else { return nil }

   if paramsDict != nil{
       components.queryItems = paramsDict!.map({ (key, value) -> URLQueryItem in
           return URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
       })
   }

   if isParamsAsQuery{
       let request = URLRequest(url: components.url!);
       return request;
   }

   if isParamsAsBody{
       let url = URL(string: urlStr);
       var request = URLRequest(url: url!);

       let bodyStr = components.percentEncodedQuery;
       if bodyStr != nil{
           request.httpBody = bodyStr!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
       }
       return request;
   }

   let url = URL(string: urlStr);
   let request = URLRequest(url: url!);
   return request;
   }
   ```
3. Remove below lines from your code:

   ```
   let convertedvalue : String = convertToParameters(employeeDetails)

   print("convertedvalues :   \(convertedvalue)")


   let myUrl = URL(string: "https://us-central1-pickceltest.cloudfunctions.net/rebliss/createNewUser");

   var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
   request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
   ```
4. Add following code instead of above removed code

   ```
   let urlStr = "https://us-central1-pickceltest.cloudfunctions.net/rebliss/createNewUser"

   var request = getURLRequestWith(urlStr: urlStr, paramsDict: employeeDetails, isParamsAsQuery: false, isParamsAsBody: true)
   ```
5. convert `employeeDetails` dictionary to type `[String:String]` instead of `[String:AnyObject]`

Now, try your code and it will surely work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185404/discussion-on-answer-by-mehul-thakkar-how-to-append-special-character-in-ios-usi).

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below solution works. Add percent encoding to you url.

```
// Create NSURL Ibject
let url : NSString = urlWithParams as NSString

let urlStr = url.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

let searchURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr! as String)!

// Creaste URL Request
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: searchURL as URL, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 120)

// Set request HTTP method to GET. It could be POST as well
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```